# PyMongo: Should I use single or multiple clients?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

The question is simple: should I keep all operations to a single `MongoClient`? Is single client or multiple clients better than the other?

Comment: what is the motivation to use many mongoClients?

Comment: @SalvadorDali I'm refactoring some code in which people don't store MongoClient and create a new one in each py file. I'm thinking if using one is better.

Comment: got it. I think that it is better to use one client and to assess it via [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). My motivation would be to use less resources for client and less connections a mongo should maintain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) actually maintains a connection pool.
So having multiple clients does not have any advantages. Quite the contrary, since a new client has to connect to MongoDB first, which requires a three way handshake and other overhead each time a new client is created.

Since multiple clients only have disadvantages for a single application, the answer is: Only create one client and use it everywhere you need to make a connection.

Comment: I could only think of one situation where you ever need more than one MongoClient: when you have an application which connects to more than one MongoDB.

Comment: @Philipp It depends. Multiple applications could even use the same connection pool, provided database authentication is not an issue. But in general, you are right.

Comment: You should also use multiple clients when multiprocessing:

http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing